# Dynamical system which does not define a flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I recently learned that whenever $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ and $f\in C^1$ then the given the system defined

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x} & = & f(x) \\
x(0) & = & x_0
\end{array} $$

the solutions can be viewed as a group action on $\Bbb R^n$ (a flow). In particular, I was interested by the "reversibility" condition, ie. that for every map $\phi_t$ there is an inverse map $\phi_{-t}$ such that $\phi_{-t}\phi_t$ is the identity map.

I want to verify my example of a function $f\notin C^1$ and corresponding solutions which are not reversible. My idea is "a ball rolling off a cliff". Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases} $$

Let the initial condition $x(0)=x_0<0$. I *believe* that one solution to this system (we cannot guarantee uniqueness) is

$$ x(t) = \begin{cases}
x_0 + t & 0 \leq t < |x_0| \\
0 & t \geq |x_0|
\end{cases}$$

So it just rolls towards the origin then stops. Now consider this problem in reverse: we have an initial point $x(0)=0$ and we have $f(x(0))=0$, so the solution is $x(t)=0$ for all $t$. Clearly not the reverse of our first solution, i.e. "the ball cannot roll back up the cliff". So, is this a proper example?

Comment: Your example defines a flow (and "weak" solutions, all that you have after all, are unique). You need to think of "faster" dynamics. Consider $x'=x^2$ for example: you have invertibility but only locally. Actually there is no example without local invertibility.

Comment: I just read the idea of weak solution, that is useful. Still I don't understand why the reversed solution defines a flow because there is no function $y$ satisfying $y(0)=0$ and $\dot{y}(0)=0$ that returns to the original point $x_0$, so it seems it is not invertible.

Comment: You cannot talk about derivatives in general for weak solutions. So you cannot think like that. Instead think of what are exactly the maps $\phi_t$ obtained from the **integral** equation. Anyways you just considered a first order equation, no condition for the derivative enters in here.